# Как скачивать файлы в заданную папку

Tags: c#, cefsharp

Какие параметры нужно задать в С# wpf чтобы Cefsharp начал скачивать файлы в заданную папку

Comment: [How to implement downloading the files to specific path](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/545)

Comment: @tym32167 То что по ссылке это все касается WinForms ! На WPF можно проще как то сделать через shceme обработчик

Comment: Так вы не указали, что у вас. Если знаете лучше способ, пишите ответом.

Comment: Есть вот такая опция ```CEF.RegisterScheme("file", new HandlerFactory());``` но я не знаю где она применяться